# How do I seed a test database for use in Appium?

Tags: android, angular, appium, nativescript, e2e-testing

I'm using [Nativescript](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/testing/end-to-end-testing/overview) 6.x with Angular 8.x and Ruby on Rails 5.x on the backend. I'm doing my End to End tests with [Appium](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-appium) + [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) + Chai. I would like to seed a test database for use in m y end to end tests.

Here is the code I'm trying to mock

```
login() {
    console.log("Login called")

    this.http.get("https://example.com/resource")
        .pipe(
            map(res =>{
                console.log(res);
            })
        )
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
        });

}
```

When I run my end to end tests with;

```
npm run e2e -- --runType device.samsung
```

Some of my tests require data to be in the database already such as the deleteItem test. Is there a way in Appium to seed a local test database with the data I need for the Appium nativescript test?

Currently I'm doing this manually in the End to End tests, ie: I'm creating an Item and then deleting it through the end to end test. The problem with this is it makes my tests long and overlapping.

Comment: `nock` is for NodeJS, I doubt it works with {N}. You may run E2E with some environment variables, may be based on which you could return mocked data from your Angular interceptor.

Comment: End to end tests are supposed to be run on a real app without mocks to test the overall integration and true business logic consistency over time

Comment: Sergey, should I just create a test user on my production backend for the end to end tests to use then?

Comment: @map7 AFAIK it's usually done that way (not only for the mobile apps we on web app also have a dedicated user though having these tests pass on a preprod server). But if you mock the requests what is the purpose of e2e then? You are mocking in unit tests and if you've done some integration tests then it's relatively equal to e2e without real requests.

Comment: @Sergey Ok but in web development I can control the backend and have a 'test' database which gets seeded each time. Currently in my mobile e2e tests I've just got a 'test' user on the real production server. Is there a way to have a test database setup and controlled in my end to end tests through appium?

Comment: How you would seed database even on web? Do you hit the APIs or run SQL / some scripts? Either ways I guess it has nothing to do with E2E. It's a step you do before running E2E tests.

Comment: @Manoj In Ruby on Rails you are given a test database and you can use fixtures to seed that database within the test. It's part of the tests in Ruby on Rails. As I come from that background I was looking for a way to do this with mobile end to end testing.

Comment: @map7 Did you check answer below?

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible, but it's not an easy way. I can explain, how something similar was done in our case. But it will not be that simple, as passing just `String` param inside `Appium`.

**1)** To start with, `Appium` is build around `WebDriver` API. Which includes bunch of functions to work with device. However, **mocking and setting database for an application is something from another kitchen** and which we don't have inside obviously. *Furthermore it's very specifc for device, application and implementation.* In order to setup database you requires some changes on client, to make it possible for particular flavors build type.

```
class WorkingDBHelper {
    private lateinit var db: DataBase

    fun createDb() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider
                 .getApplicationContext<Context>()

        if (Build.QA_REGRESSION) {
        db = Room.databaseBuilder(context, 
               TestDatabase.class, "dev/tests/database/*.db")
        } else {
         // ......
        }
    }

// .....
}
```

This changes could be very easy, and configured for specific build types. Say QA Regression types as you see above. This changes is safe (because for specific build) and now gives ability to flash DB inside app. **Note**. Above example for using `Room` as ORM solution for client. But this could be aligned with every DB.

**2)** Once your client now can work with injected inside DB files. All you need it's implement function with pushing you specific DB. This is could be done very easily (for ex. with Python and `Appium` or even adb commands before test). And you should have prebuilt databases for each test case.

```
self.active_driver.push_file(
         "dev/tests/database/*.db", self.get_database_remove_test())
```

Comment: How would my mobile app interface with the test database in this situation. I'm pointing my mobile app to a production server whilst my test database is on a local server in the office. Is it possible to also change the URL I'm calling in the mobile app through a environment variable?

Comment: @map7 1. Server type doesn't play role here. All you need it's levers in the app to intercept and replace DB usage. 2. Android app doesn't know anything about your local variable. However, you can flash everything you have on you local machine to the device application. Again, all you need it's support from application part.

Comment: And unfortunately, there is no other way for your question above. For sure.

Comment: not really. I have a URL variable set in the mobile app to point to the production server. I need to point this URL to a local database when in 'testing' mode and the 'production' database when the mobile app is compiled for release.

Comment: @map7 the whole point here, that there is no other way to do it, as I explained above.